# How to join a schedule at fixed rate thread

Tags: java, concurrency

If you have a an executor service which you submit via scheduleAtFixedRate such as this

```
public void methodName() {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do some operations
            //getSomeResults()
        }

    }, x, y, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Is it possible to join with another thread which is responsible for getSomeResults()? For example, I want the thread to wait for the getSomeResults() to finish before it continues - is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to submit a `FutureTask` rather than a `Runnable`. (A `FutureTask` is a `Runnable`, so you don't need to change anything else.)

If you create a `FutureTask` then you can have another thread invoke its `.get()` method, which will block until the task is complete, and it will return the result.

(The cleanest way will be to get rid of your `getSomeResults()` method entirely, and just use the `get()` method of `FutureTask`; but there's nothing to stop you leaving your code more or less as it is, and just using `get()` as a way of blocking, if you want to try that first to check it's all working.)

Comment: So you would create a Future Task within the current run method as described above and then submit and call get() which will block the "outer" thread until results are complete?

Comment: No, replace `new Runnable() { ... }` with a `FutureTask`. Get rid of the `Runnable` entirely.